# How to serialize a XML file to Thrift file ? (to put in HDFS)

Tags: hdfs, thrift

Since many days, I inquire a lot of informations about Big Data and especially about Thrift and HDFS/Hadoop.

I have many many XML files which I want to store in a HDFS file system. (and after, make statistics etc... from the data of these files)

So I would like to serialize my XML files with Thrift. (to validate the structure and to make durable ..)
Then, stock them in HDFS.

Is it possible ? ( XML => Thrift => HDFS ) without use RPC service.

To do the test, I would like to use a linux VM (for HDFS) and PHP language (for thrift).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the serialization part without the RPC part, yes. Look for "serializer" in the Thrift source tree, you should find some examples. If not for PHP, then for sure for some other languages.

You have to do a little work on your own, because there is not such a thing a "*the*" way to convert XML into Thrift structures. The steps are - roughly - as follows

- define the data structures to hold the XML data as Thrift IDL constructs
- generate the desired code using the Thrift Compiler
- add the serializer code as needed
- put together some code that

  - reads each XML file
  - builds the Thrift structures from it
  - serializes the data and puts them into HDFS

Depending on the layout of your XML data and on the number of XML structures used, this may need some effort. It could be an idea to generate at least the IDL file programmatically by some other tool, maybe even some of the other code needed. Thrift cannot support you with this, although it could be an option - again, depending on your current situation, language and tools available.

Comment: Thank you JensG !
I'm in an internship and I don't know so much but it's very interesting.
I'll be looking for more of "serializer"'s docs.
I wanted to use PHP but at the term, Delphi will be used.
I'll reply here when I'll have a specific question.

Comment: Oh, Delphi, cool. Then you may be interested in this particular part of the Thrift source tree: https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/delphi/test/serializer

Comment: Thank you but I don't know Delphi... I'll be left.. (but I keep this link !)

Comment: Ok I had let thrift serialization for Avro but I come back.

I don't find examples with just serialization with thrift.

I have to do my thrift structure like my xsd file (xml schema).

- I'll have only "struct" and not "service" because I don't use RPC service. Right?

I have to convert my XML file in ruby object ? right ?

Finally, my language to do my work will be Ruby...

Thank you.